# Wrong port number in mvc 4 windows Azure Request.Url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, razorengine

I am writing a small asp.net MVC4 web application. The project template is azure mvc 4 template in visual studio 2012. When I request for Request.Url in razor view I get the wrong port number. For example if my webpage url is

```
http://127.0.0.1:81/mypage
```

I get

```
http://127.0.0.1:82/mypage
```

when I get the url from Request.Url. I am running it in the default azure emulator I get with visual studio 2012.

Why the port number is wrong?
How to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. This blog article explains the reason very well.

http://blogs.staykov.net/2013/05/windows-azure-basicscompute-emulator.html

Azure emulator tries to emulate the real environment as much as possible. The emulator includes a hidden load balancer (LB). The LB roles tries bind port 81 and fails (because it is already bound) and then try to bind to 82  and so on(in my case it was successful on port 82). After this bind, Request.Url will provide the LB Url.  To get the original base url you can use this

```
var request = Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;

string baseUrl = request.UrlReferrer.Scheme + "://" +
             request.UserHostAddress + ":" +
             request.UrlReferrer.Port;
```

It can be used directly inside Razor syntax

Comment: Please edit your answer to give an actual explanation (even if just a short one). No telling if the blog link provided will remain as-is.

Comment: Ugh, this is incredibly frustrating and clearly a bug. I have an Azure role set up with a single instance, and yet still it still returns :82 when I use Request.Url. I have a few places that do a redirect to the current URL (to prevent postback retry) and they're all broken in the context of this Azure emulator.

Comment: For what it's worth, for anyone doing what I did: I was using Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString()) which was returning port 82. I changed to Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl) and that fixed my issue since it uses relative URLs and excludes the port.